# Serialized Printing Method

Tags: linux, bash, serialization, printing, automation

I am looking for a method by which I can print one document, and have a field that is incremented on each copy printed. I currently run linux, so bash in concert with several programs might be the way to go, but I'm just not sure where to start.

I have a document that is used for our business that currently is hand stamped for serialization... We would like to simply print them but cant find a method by which to increment a specific field. I would like to use either a PDF or an ODF/ODT for the document.

Thanks for any help you can give!

Comment: Try to read these pages: http://tkjacobsen.wordpress.com/2008/04/25/print-pdf-files-from-bash/, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1764094/bash-script-printing-a-pdf-to-a-pdf-in-linux. Post back or update your thread if you find a good command but still need help about it (at least with scripting).

Comment: I'll not add this as an "answer" because I don't know if this is doable in OOO/LibreOffice. However, in MS Office (Windows), you can simply define a VBA macro called "Print" to match the native print command. In there, you would update the serial number then call the native print function. This would then be used when using the GUI to print. I've often used this in the past on the Save function to add a "poor mans" GIT to Word to keep versions.

Answer (score 0):

How is the document produced at the first place?

If you master that process, you could certainly add serialization at that level. For instance if using LibreOffice you could do that in LibreOffice. If using a text formatter (like LaTeX, Lout, ....) just emit the formatting instructions (e.g. the `.tex` or `.lout` source file) with some unique counting (perhaps simpler to do in some scripting language like Python or Ocaml).

<sup>Then run the relevant tool to get a `.pdf` file.</sup>